# Is there a purpose to a symbolic link that points back to the directory containing it?

Tags: linux, bash, symlink

When Gogs docker installation is run it creates a symbolic link `/data/git/git` that points back to the parent folder:

```
lrwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000             9 May 13 19:37 git -> /data/git
```

I'm trying to understand whether there is some benefit to doing this.  Below are some examples of using the link:

```
/data/git $ cd git
/data/git $ cd /data/git/git
/data/git $
```

Thoughts?

Comment: It won't always point there (otherwise you wouldn't need it you could just go up one). If you chose some custom locations during the install the software might still want to be able to get to the root of the install so that link would point someplace else.

Comment: @user1794469 that might be worth turning into an answer if you're sure it can change.

Comment: @terdon I would have to dig through the installation to be sure. If the comment is too speculative i can delete it.

Comment: @user1794469 not at all. It would be great if you could make it into a full answer but if you don't have the time, it is still useful as a comment. Someone else might make it into an answer.

Comment: For the gogs docker installation the gogs docker image exposes the `/data` volume as the place where everything related to configuration and git repositories are placed.  So the repositories go in `/data/git/gogs-repositories`.  On a regular installation gogs writes repositories to `/home/git/gogs-repositories`.  I think the intention was to provide a symbolic link so that the gogs core can write to `/home/git/gogs-repositories`, and the result will be redirected to `/data/git/gogs-repositories` but I don't see how this link helps with that.  Perhaps I should ask a more gogs specific question.

Comment: Asked a related question here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283963/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-symbolic-git-link-inside-the-data-git-folder-of

Comment: Not familiar with Gogs, but... I can imagine it's a matter of providing a known path to the directory of interest for some tool or another. I'm thinking if you searched any included scripts (and possibly git hooks, since it looks like git is being used), you might find a reason for it.

Comment: You mention it's created as part of the install, so it could even be a simple mechanism for something else to check if the install had run. Weird, but do-able.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first reason that comes to mind is that since that is an absolute link (it points to `/data/git` and not `../git`), this will allow it to still work even if you move the directory later.

So, say you install the system in `/data/git/git` and then decide to move the final `git` directory somewhere else, say `/foo/bar/git`. Now, the `/foo/bar/git/git` link will still work and point to `/data/git` which might contain the necessary configuration files or whatever.

Comment: I'm sure you are right.  They have done something similar for the log directory.